# error in import project from github

Tags: java, android-studio

When I'm importing following a project from GitHub, I am getting 2 error's

## Project

https://github.com/davidanthonymalone/Beer-Finder

## Error

> Error: Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> Please read the following process output to find out more:
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: It seems your machine might not have enough ram to run the Android Studio?

Comment: That sentence makes no sense.